# Why Are Array-Like Objects Used in Javascript Over Native Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

It's very common in Javascript to come across Array-Like objects with some similarities to the build in Array type but without all of its methods or features.  So much so that there are some tricks to convert Array-Like objects to "real" arrays for further manipulation.

This is even mentioned in [Javascript: The Definitive Guide](http://books.google.com/books?id=2weL0iAfrEMC&pg=PT144&lpg=PT144&dq=David+Flanagan+array-like&source=bl&ots=%5F8-ymy%5F45C&sig=I%5FQ6RRm%5FrnyI5%5FnzTFmDZVUkeBM&hl=en&ei=JC85S6mEK5D34Abp3qWqCA&sa=X&oi=book%5Fresult&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CA8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).

The questions is why is this pattern so common?  Why not prefer the built-in Array type in all these cases?

Comment: Possibly a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971389/array-like-object-in-javascript

Comment: For example: `arguments` is designed to be unmutable. That would not be the case if it was an array.

Comment: @elusive, the `arguments` object is mutable, you can change the value of its properties. The index-named properties are *linked* to the function's FormalParameters, if you change the value of `arguments[0]`, the change will be reflected on the first named parameter of the function. Strict mode on ECMAScript 5, introduce some restrictions, but the object is still mutable.

Comment: @CMS: You are right. Made a mistake here. It is _very_ early in the morning. Excellent answer, by the way. +1!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, speaking about *core* Javascript objects, the `arguments` is a good example to talk about.

In this case it has been an *array-like object* since the beginning, appeared in the ECMAScript 1th Edition Specification already as a simple object.

Why? I think at that time there were only four built-in `Array` methods, and maybe the designer didn't think it worthed too much, later the change was proposed, but Microsoft (part of the TC39 committee) didn't approved the change, the fear of *breaking the web* has always been present.

Now going to *host objects*, the DOM, `NodeLists` come to my mind, I think they didn't wanted to use the native `Array` type due the dynamic behavior of these objects.

`NodeLists` generally are *live* objects, their structure is reflects any change on the underlying DOM structure...

Personally I like array-objects, because they are really lightweight, before ECMAScript 5, there were a lot of restrictions in core methods, regarding the usage of user-defined array-like objects.

For example, the `apply` method of function objects, in ECMAScript <= 3, allowed only either a real array or an arguments object as its second argument, now in ES5, the following is possible:

```
var arrayLike = {0: 'hello ', 1:'world', length:2};
(function (a,b) { alert(a+b); }).apply(null, arrayLike);
```

See also:

- [Why isn't a function's arguments object an array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242485/why-isnt-a-functions-arguments-object-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: I suspect that the primary objection to turning `arguments` into an `Array` is that it would make an use of `arguments` *even harder* to optimize than it already is.

Comment: @Gabe: Well, in the last discussions before ES5 got accepted, optimization wasn't the issue, the problem was backwards-compatibility, specifically with the `toString` and `toLocaleString` methods. The change even got to the draft state, but wasn't really straight-forward, they used an `Array` object, but defined two own properties (`toString` and `toLocaleString`) pointing to the methods on `Object.prototype`. After some time the change was dropped out from the ES5 draft. At the end, the optimization problems regarding the `arguments` object are solved on ES5 strict mode.