# Which Objects in JavaScript have a .length property? (aka Why does Underscore _.each treat my Function Object like an Array?)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've been under the impression that only `Array` objects have a `.length` property. But, then again, I've also seen mentions of objects that are "array-like". I've not looked into this, and now it seems like my ignorance of this topic in JS may be biting me in the ass. Case in point:

I've got the following code:

```
var View = function(options) {
  // code
};

_.extend(View, Backbone.Events, {

    make_children: function(parent) {
      // code
    }

});
```

Later on, I use this `View` `Function` with Underscore's `_.each`, which decides this function object is an array, because it has a `.length` property:

```
// Code from Underscore.js's `_.each`:
} else if (obj.length === +obj.length) { // This is true
  for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) { // **So, execution goes here**
    if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return
  }
} else {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (_.has(obj, key)) { // **Execution does __not__ go here**
      if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
    }
  }
}
```

This results in code that doesn't work, because `obj[i]` where `i` is an integer index, is not actually defined on my `obj` `View`. To be precise, in the above code, `obj[0]` is `undefined` while `obj.length === +obj.length` is `true` and `obj.length` is `1`. What's going on here?

**Addendum**

Underscore's chief maintainer says the following on https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/pull/510:

> Simply making each reject function objects doesn't really help. We've
>   made a conscious decision to use a numerical length property to detect
>   array-like objects.
>
> Instead, don't pass function objects to `each`.

**Addendum 2**

Realized that since I couldn't pass a function object to `_.each`, I could just "cast it" to a regular object like so:

```
var regular_obj = _.extend({}, View);
```

Comment: http://dochub.io/#javascript/length

Comment: All [functions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15) have a length property at least, as do Strings.

Comment: @magritte: +++1 for pointing me to dochub.io. never been there before.

Comment: `obj[1]` will never get called because if length is 1, and i is 1, then 1<1 is false and the for loop will stop executing.

Comment: @TravisJ My bad, I meant 0, good catch

Comment: BTW: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1971653/139010

Comment: So why are you passing function objects to a function that expects an array (or array–like object)?

Comment: @RobG: Why do you say that? I am passing a function object to a function that works upon any kind of object, but chooses a mode of iteration by looking for `.length` __before__ using `in`/`_.has`, which would be what I'm looking for but not getting here.

Comment: Where is `_.each` called in your code above?

Comment: @MattBall: It's not called in the code above. It's called elsewhere, after a `_.contains`, which uses `_.any` which in turn uses `_.each`.

Comment: I wonder if you're just not meant to pass functions as property values in `_.extend` – perhaps that's not idiomatic underscore. Disclaimer: I'm not much of an underscore user.

Comment: @MattBall: Well, I don't know what you're "supposed to do"—I've been trying to say as close as possible to Backbone/Underscore use/convention/style because I'm using those libraries for my MV* and utility belt. In those codebases, they use `_.extend` mostly to _.extend objects, particularly to add their events library mix-in (`Backbone.Events`) to prototypes. But I wanted to mix `Backbone.Events` into certain constructors (so, `Functions`), and use them as pubsub dispatchers because that's where that behavior seemed natural.

Comment: @MattBall: I think it's actually really really neat how you can do this sort of thing. It's some mid-to-late binding, almost like PHP late static.

Comment: For example, I've got an abstract "super" View constructor that all my Views inherit prototypically from and use as their constructor. My views collection listens to events triggered on this "super" View constructor. I don't need any other objects, and it seems so perfect as this "super" view is the factory that produces my views. I'm just writing test/spec code now to examine this Function object's properties. In application code there's no direct examination, just ducking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that `underscore.js`, much like `jquery`, both use the `.length` property as a flag in their `each` functions. When the `length` property is present, the function assumes that the argument passed can be iterated through with a normal for loop. The reason behind this logic is there is an expectation that when the `length` property is defined then it is possible to iterate through the argument **in order** which is why the for loop is used.

The result of misusing `length` is essentially a name collision where there is an unintended result. I would suggest changing `length` to another synonym such as `size` or `capacity` or `totalViews`, etc.

---

Edit

If there are *no other alternatives* for you to use, and you must have length in there while still retaining `_.each`'s functionality, then you can slightly hack it. This plug works with the minified version of underscore version 1.4.3

```
var s = Array.prototype.ForEach;
var r = {};
var myEach = function (n,t,e){if(null!=n)if(s&&n.forEach===s)n.forEach(t,e);else if(n.length===+n.length&&typeof(n[0])!="undefined"){for(var u=0,i=n.length;i>u;u++)if(t.call(e,n[u],u,n)===r)return}else for(var a in n)if(_.has(n,a)&&t.call(e,n[a],a,n)===r)return};
_.each=myEach;
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xa5qq/

Basically what it does is use `forEach` when the `length` property exists but `typeof(yourObject[0]) == "undefined"`.

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying: first I copy the Function object's `.length` to the more appropriately named property, and then I should get rid of it or do something to it such that it doesn't pass that test? ...And I just watched this presentation re: built-in manipulation yesterday: http://blip.tv/jsconf/jsconf2011-andrew-dupont-everything-is-permitted-extending-built-ins-5211542

Comment: @dimadima—per [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15), you can't modify a function's length property other than by changing the number of formal parameters in its declaration. You can't delete it either: `the length property of a built-in Function object described in this clause has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }`.

Comment: @dimadima - If this is an artifact of the framework then that was an unfortunate choice they made. I am not sure where else it is used in the framework so it may be required elsewhere. I noticed that you pulled up some source code which is a great way to get to the heart of the issue you are facing. If you do strip the length property (as in you didn't explicitly add it and the framework chose unwisely to add it) then make sure you do not break other functionality.

Comment: @RobG: Yeah, just found that out by trial and error. Thanks for confirming :D

Comment: @TravisJ: As @RobG points out, looks like I'm stuck with this Function's `.length` the way it is. I'll have to figure out a way around somehow. This is all for testing/spec anyway. Worst case scenario... I will write my out `each` testing util.

Comment: @RobG - If an object has an explicit length property defined, you can use `delete View["length"]`.

Comment: @TravisJ: Oh yeah: if we're talking about that fiddle, I'm talking about `View.length` (which is immutable and 0, since `View` has no specified args), not the `.length` of a `view` (lower case, instance)

Comment: @dimadima - Please see edit for a hack of underscore's each to use if there is literally no way to remove the built in length property from breaking your code.

Comment: @TravisJ, there is not, sadly, any way to remove the code. And, I'll one-up you. Unless you hack the Underscore code itself (which I'm not gonna do--just not worth it), there's no way to selectively swap in/out the methods it uses internally: I just tried and realized that that is why internally, underscore uses closure references to its own methods. So while it exposes its `_.each` as `_.each` it also defines it as `var each` within its closure and uses that `each`. So, you can't modify its behavior without hacking the code. I've come up with a way simpler hack that I'm going to post above.

Comment: @dimadima - "var each = _.each". This is a reference pointer, and using `_.each` will in fact update that reference in *all* places. This version will change the functionality across `_` when used.

Comment: @TravisJ: not internally, though. I can change `_.each` but since I'm really using `_.contains`, which uses `var any` (closure) which uses `var each` (closure), I don't end up changing the pointers inside the closure. I end up changing the pointer at `window._.each`

Comment: @dimadima - Perhaps that would be true if `_` were instantiated after you issue `_.each`. In that case, you should still be able to use `_.prototype.each` in order to handle future cases.

Comment: @TravisJ: I tested it, but it appeared the pointer did not change, and when I looked at the Underscore code, it seemed to make sense that the pointers inside the closure wouldn't change by my modification of the pointer in `window._`. I think I tested it correctly. Anyway, this has been a rather unexpected detour! All for testing/specing. Sometimes it hurts.

Comment: @dimadima - Hm, that is unfortunate :( I was hoping there was a way to affect it externally. Perhaps you could post your findings of `each` and `length` (being automatically assigned) as bug on their forum? Alternatively, you could also just manually go in to the script and swap out the code yourself :)

Comment: I expect the underscore.js each method is intentionally generic so you can pass it any type of object with a length property. The solution is to not pass it such an object if you don't want to iterate over it based on its `length`.

Comment: @RobG - `each` is setup to conditionally iterate. It will use `for in` for objects, unless they have the length property defined. It was my understanding that the framework was adding this property automatically which is why I suggested this (which is still generic). In my opinion, it does not make sense to iterate an object with a for(;;) loop because numbered indexes will show undefined values.

Answer (score 5):

> Which Objects in JavaScript have a `.length` property?

By oh-so-tautological definition, any object which has a `length` property.

[This happens to include functions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

> `length` is a property of a function object, and indicates how many arguments the function expects, i.e. the number of formal parameters.

This is also array-like, because it has a `length`:

```
var foo = {
    bar: true,
    baz: 'quux',
    length: 42
}
```

Comment: Ugh. Annoying. Could not find that by Googling, sadly. Must have been my fault. Thanks.

Comment: Got any recommendations as to how I might make this work, then? What should I... use my own `_.each`-type function?

Comment: I think [ECMA_262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15) says it pretty well: "Unless otherwise specified, this value is equal to the largest number of named arguments … including optional parameters"

Comment: Agreed with @RobG's comment on your OP. I'm not sure your problem has anything to do with the fact that `Function` has a `length` property.