# Getting length (size? count?) of an array in Parse.com cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, underscore.js

I believe in javascript, arrays have a ".count" property.  However, I believe that when writing Parse cloud code, effectively you **cannot use this** since .count is in a word, used by Parse (for queries).

(1) Is that correct, and is the reason I gave correctly stated or a shambles?

I believe (it seems to work) you can go ahead and use **.length** in Parse cloud code for the length of an array; but I'm confused "why" since javascript doco says .length

(2) Is that correct - if so why can it be done?

You inevitably use "underscore" library in Parse projects; in fact does that library offer a way to get the size/length/count of an array?

(3) Is there yet another way, using _ ?

I swear I have seen Parse cloud code using "size" (something or other like that) in relation to arrays;

(4) Is there an idiom using something like 'size' ?

Finally, indeed, considering this typical example of using _,

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Employee", function(request)
    {

    var company = request.object.get("company");
    var query = new Parse.Query("Employee");
    query.equalTo("company", company);
    query.include("company");

    var justEmails = new Array();

    query.each(function(employee)
        {
        var thatEmail = employee.get("email");
        justEmails.push(thatEmail);
        }
    ).then(function()
        {
        var kount = justEmails.length;
        console.log(">>>        count is " + kount );
        justEmails = _.uniq(justEmails);
        kount = justEmails.length;
        console.log(">>>        but count is now " + kount );
        });

    });
```

(5) is there a way to do that in "one line", saying something like `_.uniq(justEmails).sizeOrWhateverTheHell();`

Finally in summary,

(6) what then is the best and most sensible and most idimoatic way to get simply the length of an array, in javascript in the Parse cloud code milieu -- is it indeed .length?

Comment: Incidentally, I observe there are some [extreme subtleties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488754/which-objects-in-javascript-have-a-length-property-aka-why-does-underscore) in related issues; here, I'm asking a more basic "help me javascript experts!" dumbass question.  Thx!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: HI Math, I really appreciate the link.  That may clear one issue I asked about.  Things are quite different and specific when, specifically, you're messing with Parse cloud code.  You may know the answer to question (5) for instance?

Comment: No they aren't. Arrays are arrays. Don't overthink it.

Comment: [_.uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) returns an array. All of this stuff is documented; look it up.

Comment: `_.uniq(justEmails).length` for #5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct and the best way to get the number of elements of an array in javascript (and in Parse cloud code) is to use [array.length](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp)

Length is the property of the array, whereas size is a function that's defined in some javascript frameworks. Always use the length property to get the number of elements in an array.

Comment: Two equally impressive and expert answers - I thought it good to bounty the new user!  Outstanding and thanks, gang!

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no such thing as `count`. Arrays (and strings) have a `.length` property. Use it.
2. I have no idea what this is asking.
3. No, use `.length`.
4. See **3**
5. `_.uniq(whatever).length`
6. See **1**

It's just JavaScript.